# Accessing global state in Redux reducer?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

How can I access global state from my reducer?

Currently in my actions file I have this function and many functions require userId:

```
export const getMyUserData = (userId) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(fetchingData()); 
  accessing(`api/${userId}`, (res) => {
    fetchComplete(res);
  });
};
```

Instead of passing the Id value.

```
const Id = useSelector(state => state.auth.userId)
export const getMyUserData = () => (dispatch) => {
};
```

Is this the correct way to access the global state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access current state using the second argument passed to the thunk.

Like this

```
const getUserId = state => state.auth.userId

export const getMyUserData = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  const userId = getUserId(getState())

  dispatch(fetchingData()); 

  accessing(`api/${userId}`, (res) => {
    fetchComplete(res);
  });
};
```